# `auto.arima` warning message: NaNs produced (in coefficient variance matrix)

Tags: r

I got a warning from function `auto.arima` in "forecast" package in R, which said:

```
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)) : NaNs produced
```

I realize that the problem appears because of trying to obtain the square root of negative numbers, but I don't know how it can be solved.

What I did was:

```
orig <- ts(c(-0.001730532,-0.035105068,-0.094437577,-0.149320148,-    
0.146847960,-0.129048208))
auto.arima(orig,stepwise=FALSE,approx=FALSE)
```

And what I got was:

```
Series: orig 
ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2      ma1      ma2    drift
      0.7136  -0.958  -0.8951  -0.0594  -0.0254
s.e.     NaN     NaN   0.3655      NaN      NaN

sigma^2 estimated as Inf:  log likelihood=14.29
AIC=-16.59   AICc=-58.59   BIC=-18.93
Warning message:
In sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)) : NaNs produced
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the model is much too large for such a short series (only 6 observations), and while the model can be estimated, the standard errors cannot. The following will help:

```
auto.arima(orig, stepwise=FALSE, approximation=FALSE, max.order=2)
```

I'll update the code to prevent this sort of thing happening.